# unexpected results writing ondblclick event with php

Tags: javascript, php

i have the following echo in php:

```
echo "ondblclick=kardex(codigo=$codigo AND comprada<>0);";
```

i expect this echo result:

```
ondblclick="kardex(codigo=001 AND comprada<>0);"
```

but i get this:

```
ondblclick="kardex(codigo=001" and="" comprada<="">0);
```

How is the correct writing?

Comment: Double-click in web applications is generally (if not universally) considered to be a terrible idea. In any case that syntax is just wrong; it's not JavaScript.

Comment: _"but i get this"_ - where? When you inspect the DOM? Or in the actual HTML output produced by the PHP script? Have you checked what the variable actually contains? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your echo should produce a valid syntax, which it currently doesn't: you will need `"`s

This should work: `echo "ondblclick=\"kardex(codigo=$codigo AND comprada<>0);\"";`

---

Alternatively you can use `'`, but you cannot interpolate with them:

`echo ('ondblclick="kardex(codigo=' . $codigo . ' AND comprada<>0);"');`

Comment: It's still not valid syntax.

Comment: What de you mean by not valid syntax? What is wrong?

Comment: What do you think the `<>` operator does in JavaScript? And that first expression, where the comparison is done with `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: Oh you were talking about the js. Yeah that doesn't make sense, but it isn't really what the question is about. I guess, I should have mentioned that, but I didn't really pay attention to it.